# Get navigation controller property after embedding it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController which i have embedded in a Navigation controller using:

```
Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller
```

Now i want to get the upper bar height for some calculations but i cant ctrl+drag

anything to use the needed property.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "upper bar" is the UINavigationController's `navigationBar`. And thus your view controller has a reference to it.

If you are trying to do auto layout, stay inside the embedded view controller and pin to the Top Layout Guide. That is what it is for.

Comment: Yeah but i cannot create a ctrl+drag property to the UINavigationController, since it is embedded in my UIViewController in the way described above... so i cant get the navigation bar property...